# Where does the idea come from that the KJV is the proper bible to be used?

Tags: kjv, kjv-onlyism

I have heard (mostly from the older generations) that the KJV is the only bible to be used, and all the other ones are changing the bible. Where does this idea come from? Is it a churches teaching or the individual opinions of people? I have learned from my studies that it is probably the least reliable bible, so I was wondering why people set their minds so much upon the KJV.

Answer (score 1):

**Where does the idea come from that the KJV is the proper bible to be used?**

People have various reasons for preferring the KJV.

1. There is no copyright so it can  be used without worry that someone will sue them.
2. Some people believe that it is supernaturally "preserved" by God to be the accurate translation.
3. Some prefer that the language contemporary with Shakespeare is preferable.
4. Some prefer the fact that is translated from the TR as opposed to many newer translations based on the Alexandrian Greek manuscript.

There is a natural defensive reaction to stick with the familiar when the new encompasses much that is suspicious. Readers Digest has a condensed "Bible" version. There are gender neutral bibles and other "bibles" that either emphasize some viewpoint or push some agenda.